# What is the proper way to have a constant string throughout my entire Silverlight C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to have a constant `string kURL = "http://www.myurl.com/";` throughout my entire project. What's the proper way to do this in a Windows Phone 7 app?

Where would I put this code and what should the proper syntax be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a .Common project for things that you may need to access from all of your projects in your solution (like constants, extension methods, utils etc.), in there simply create Constants class with any Constants that you may need.

Like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
    #region Nested type: Urls

    public static class Urls
    {
        public static readonly string MyUrl = "http://blablabla.com";
    }

    #endregion
```

}

Usage would be:

```
Constants.Urls.MyUrl
```

Good luck.

Edit Note: Changed to const as per [Gabes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310574/gabe) suggestion

Edit Note2: Changed to static readonly per [lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336186/lukas) suggestion

Comment: I recommend making it constant (`const`).

Comment: What do you mean "either way"? If you don't use `const`, it is constant in name only. Any part of the program can change it at any time, even accidentally.

Comment: I would be very careful to make it inside common project. I would it internal or readonly. here is why -> http://www.stum.de/2009/01/14/const-strings-a-very-convenient-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot/

Comment: Yes, publicly exported `const` values are a bad idea.  They create all sorts of really hard to debug headaches if the value somehow changes.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple tutorial on creating Global Consts in C#. I've used this for .NET, but not Windows Phone. I would assume the same conventions are followed.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable

Answer (score 1):

If you want the URL be accessible to both Xaml and C# and if you need this to be accessible to whole project and not whole solution. create a static resource in App.xaml like

```
<System:String x:Key="kURL">"http://www.myurl.com/"</System:String>
```

define the namespace "System"

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Now, you can use this both in xaml and c# code.

In C# code you can use

```
App.Current.Resources["kURL"];
```

In Xaml, lets say if you need to use for a textBlock

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource kURL}" Name="textBlock1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You define variable in app class and Make use of it.
As App class is the main and is available thought the application

Comment: App class will not accessible in other class libraries. Because App stays in the project that is executable.